# VS Code Python, entry in Run&Debug not present in launch.json

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just started using VS Code to develop in Python, I have the official Python extension installed, and I'm trying to configure the Run&Debug menu.

In one of my workspaces, I created the following launch.json file, with THREE configurations (test.py, preview.py and Project Tests):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "test.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "./test.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "variablePresentation": {
                "all": "inline",
                "class": "group",
                "function": "hide",
                "special": "hide"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "preview.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "./preview.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "variablePresentation": {
                "all": "inline",
                "class": "group",
                "function": "hide",
                "special": "hide"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Project Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "some_folder",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "variablePresentation": {
                "all": "inline",
                "class": "group",
                "function": "hide",
                "special": "hide"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, in the Run&Debug menu I see FOUR entries..."test.py", "preview.py" and "Project Tests", the ones I configured in launch.json, and "Python: File", which is applied to the currently open file in the IDE.

[image]

I was assuming this "Python: File" might be some default option which is always present, but then I have another workspace where I created launch.json with only one entry (process.py):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "process.py",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "./process.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true,
            "variablePresentation": {
                "all": "inline",
                "class": "group",
                "function": "hide",
                "special": "hide"
            }
        },
        
    ]
}
```

and here I only have the corresponding entry in the menu as well:

[image]

I tried deleting and recreating the launch.json file in the first workspace, but the result is always the same.
How does this work precisely?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/src/client/debugger/extension/configuration/dynamicdebugConfigurationService.ts#L27. So now the question is why you're not getting it in another workspace. Is the Python extension enabled in the workspace where you don't see this? And have you done [anything to trigger its activation](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/blob/main/package.json#L66)?

Comment: The Python extension is enabled in the other workspace, and I did run some debugging there already. In workspace 2, I created the launch.json both manually and with the GUI option, but the menu entry for the current file always disappears when the configuration is removed from launch.json (it's always there in the first workspace). In workspace 2 I can select "Add Configuration", add it for the current file and I will see the entry in the menu, but if I remove it from launch.json it disappears (which, again, doesn't happen in the first workspace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copying your `launch.json` does not lead to the same problem.

So I don't think this is only a problem with the launch or debug itself. I have a speculation that you can try it out:

[image]

Click Python and choose Python File then **click on the gear.**

[image]

[image]

This will add `Python: File` related settings in `launch.json` for you, and then try to manually delete them after saving `launch.json`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion in the second workspace. I selected "Python" from the lower part of the GUI menu, but this did NOT add anything to the launch.json file. However, now in the top half I have permanently "Python: File", as in the first workspace. So, I imagine the settings for this are configured in some other file?

Comment: @Carlo I have updated my answer. If you click on the gear, it will add relevant settings in the launch. Then you can manually delete them, which should solve the problem.